# Loading Apache CXF SOAP webservices without validating wsdl files

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

The Apache CXF based SOAP web services works fine in a setup with internet connection available.
However a client has reported problem in a setup with no internet connection available.
The wsdl files is dependent on couple of xsd files which inturn references many external online sites.
The error getting is something similar as follows.

```
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing file 
/........../webservices/WEB-INF/wsdl/xxx.xsd java.net.UnknownHostException www.w3.org errors
```

Is it possible to have web services loaded without validating wsdl files?
The cxf-beans.xml too has external references.
One option I could think of defining all external references (online references) as local to file systems. But this looks non practical since it has lot of references.
Any other suggestions to make it work in a system with no internet connections?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve parsing error on startup of the product by removing wsdlLocation from cxf-beans.xml and also from the @javax.jws.WebService annotation in the SOAP service implementation class.